# How do I retrieve a document along with just one of its child documents in C#?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following document in mongo

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e7b6cb9606503483494c63a"},"ProductId":{"$binary":{"base64":"V9+9bOaj8kyWrPwdAm0rBQ==","subType":"03"}},"ProductName":"TestProduct1","ProductItems":[{"_t":"ProductItem","ProductId":{"$binary":{"base64":"V9+9bOaj8kyWrPwdAm0rBQ==","subType":"03"}},"Code":"TP1A"},
{"_t":"ProductItem","ProductId":{"$binary":{"base64":"V9+9bOaj8kyWrPwdAm0rDE==","subType":"03"}},"Code":"TP1B"}]}
```

What I want to do is return by a query on ProductItem.Code that returns a product with the single matching child item. So preserving the object structure but eliminating all but the single matching child.

I have tried

```
Product prod = new Product();
IMongoCollection<Product> products = _database.GetCollection<Product>("Products");
var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.ElemMatch(x=>x.ProductItems, x=>x.Code==code);
prod = products.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
return prod;
```

but this just ends up returning the root document and all of the children instead of just the root document and the single child that I searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can project the matched document in the array with the positional operator. This is `[-1]` in C# (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

```cs
var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.ElemMatch(x=>x.ProductItems, x=>x.Code==code);
var projection = Builders< Product >.Projection.Include(x => x.ProjectItems[-1])

var found = await collection.Find(filter, projection).ToListAsync();
var matchedProductItem =  found[0].ProductItems.First();
```

Comment: I had to make a change "var found = products.Find(filter).Project<Product>(projection).ToList();" However this results in a timeout. It also looks like this will result in returning a ProductItem rather than a Product containing the ProductItem?

Comment: My bad. the error was an issue with the server.  This works thanks. Just out of interest does this return all the elements of the child array and then use linq to select the correct one or does it do all of that on the database side?